# ¿Cómo mantener la proporción en un anchor pane en javaFX(Scene builder)?

Tags: java, javafx, scenebuilder

He estado trabajando en un anchor pane. Lo que quiero hacer es que dicho anchor pane mantenga las proporciones. Es decir, en los pref width y height definí 600 y 400, pero cuando corro el programa , puedo estirar la ventana y las proporciones no se mantienen, es decir, puedo estirarlo horizontalmente por toda la pantalla y el fondo se deforma. estoy pensando en algo como esto:
[image](aparecen bordes si el alto y ancho de la ventana no esta proporcionado con la aplicación)
Ademas, cuando trato de poner un boton, quiero que la posicion quede relativa al centro. Si solo lo pongo en el anchor pane, cuando maximizo la ventana queda como en una esquina, pero si utilizo constraints queda por ejemplo a "n" pixeles de un borde, y eso no es lo que yo quiero. Es decir, que si yo defino el boton en x/3 (donde x es la longitud horizontal de la ventana) quede siempre a esa distancia, y que cuando cambio el tamaño de la ventana la proporción se mantenga(no trabajar con pixeles sino con longitud relativas a los bordes)

ya busque en español e inglés y no encontré nada.
Gracias de antemano(y perdón si algo no quedó claro)

Answer (score 0):

Ya encontré la solución. En vez de utilizar un anchorpane, utilicé un gridpane, y puse el tamaño de los botones al máximo(rellenan toda la cuadrícula). Así mantiene posiciones relativas, así, si coloco un botón en el centro, ahí se quedará

Comment: Allan, estaría bien si añadieras la solución completa con código, ya que puede ayudar a alguien en un futuro.